# Select data from database

Tags: mysql

I want to load data from database but how to get data in specific colmun
More Explanation:
lets say that we have a table called players, Then we have three columns "Username, Password and E-mail"
Now, if we want to select the email of the player who called "Nezo" how we can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward SELECT statement.  I'd take some time to familiarize myself with the [MySQL manual on SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), since it is among the most basic MySQL commands.

In this case, our `select_expr` (SELECT expression) is going to be the column from the table we're looking for, `E-mail`, and we're going to need to restrict the query to only look at the e-mail of the user named 'Nezo' using a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT `E-mail` FROM `players` WHERE `Username` = 'Nezo';
```